# How to use apache license in my project which will be LGPL

Tags: lgpl, apache-license

I want to use LGPL for my project, can I use some source code which is apache licensed ?

If I only use the apache licensed component as library in my project, how should I make the clarification in my project ? Do I need to put some information about apache license at the beginning of source code which uses the library?

Answer (score 2):

As the Apache license [is deemed compatible with the (L)GPL v3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses), you can use Apache licensed code in your LGPL project.

If you use the Apache licensed code only in the form of a library, the conventional way is

- keep the Apache licensed library in a separate directory/sub-tree of the project
- mention in your documentation (readme) that you use such-and-such library and under which license it is being distributed.

In your source code, you don't need to mention that a function/class comes from a separate library. The fact that it has a different license should be obvious from the copyright statements in the respective source files.

Comment: I need to copy some functions from the apache licensed source code into my project, and make some changes to them. In this case, should I declare in the top area of my file that some functions are from apache licensed code ?

Comment: @crypto__: If possible, I would keep those functions in a separate file from the rest of your code and make it clear in that file where you got the code from. If a separate file is not feasible, I would state at the top of the file that different licenses apply to different functions and which license applies to which function.

Comment: The linked page doesn't mention LGPL imho. It means LGPL and Apache are both compatible with _GPL_, so if you publish your project under GPL it would be no problem. But I don't know when it comes to LGPL.

Comment: @FelixYan: The only difference between the GPL and the LGPL is that the LGPL allows a covered library to be dynamically linked to a closed-source application, which the GPL doesn't. As the LGPL is more permissive than the GPL, licenses compatible with the GPL are also compatible with the LGPL.

Answer (score 1):

GPLv3 and LGPLv3 licenses are be compatible with the Apache v2 license, meaning you can incorporate Apache v2-licensed code into an LGPLv3 library. (Note that the reverse is not true, see https://www.apache.org/licenses/GPL-compatibility.html).

As for the way in which you used the Apache v2 licensed code, the Apache v2 does not apply too many restrictions. If you were to copy a handful of functions (or even lines from a function) into your LGPLv3-licensed code, you'd need to do the following:

1. Ensure the applicable copyright, patent, trademark, and attribution notices are reproduced in your source (e.g. placed prominently in a comment block near the top of your header file).
2. Note which code that license applies to. If you've copied functions, you could e.g. place a notice that identifies the functions by name. If you copied a block of code from within a function, you might delimit it with comments.
3. Include a copy of the Apache License v2 in your code. Typically, I put these in a "Third-party licenses" folder in my documentation folder.
4. If the code comes with a NOTICE file, reproduce this in its entirety.

Note that the other requirements of the Apache License are adequately covered by the LGPLv3 license itself.